# Present SCNView from other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, scenekit

I have the usual view controller, and i want to show the other ViewController that contains SCNView

If I use `presentViewController` or `showViewController` its doesn't work. It finished immediately. I mean, scene doesn't show.

Thanks for the answers!

Sorry for my bad English

Lets a describe my project. I have ViewContrioller that contains the main menu, and I have SCNView that contains the fall of a dice. 
This is the ViewController that contains SCNView:

```
    self.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"dice.dae"];
    self.scene.physicsWorld.gravity  = SCNVector3Make(0, -16, 0);
    self.scene.physicsWorld.speed = 2.5;

    self.cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    self.cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    [self.scene.rootNode addChildNode:self.cameraNode];
    self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 20, 20);
    self.cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(self.cameraNode.transform,M_PI/3.0, -5, 0, 0);


    self.diceNode = [self.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"dice" recursively:YES];

    SCNPhysicsBody* diceBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode: self.diceNode options:nil ]];
    self.diceNode.physicsBody = diceBody;
    CGFloat zVelocity = arc4random()%10+5;
    CGFloat xVelocity = arc4random()%5;
    self.diceNode.physicsBody.velocity = SCNVector3Make(xVelocity, 0, -zVelocity);
    CGFloat xAngVelocity = arc4random()%12 + 5;
    CGFloat yAngVelocity = arc4random()%4 + 1;
    CGFloat zAngVelocity = arc4random()% 13 + 9;
    self.diceNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity = SCNVector4Make(-xAngVelocity, yAngVelocity, -zAngVelocity, 0.8);
    self.diceNode.physicsBody.mass = 100.0;
    self.diceNode.physicsBody.friction = 1;
    SCNNode *field = [self.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"field" recursively:YES];
    field.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode:field options:nil]];
    field.physicsBody.friction = 1;
     self.scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;
    self.scnView.frame = self.view.frame;
    self.scnView.scene = self.scene;
    self.scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    self.scnView.showsStatistics = YES;
    self.scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.scnView.delegate = self;
```

I try show this ViewController from main menu

```
  DiceScene* dice = [[DiceScene alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:dice animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"completion");
    }];
```

And my DiceScene does't show, it completion immediately without errors.

Comment: Can you please provide some code, what u have tried.

Comment: so `DiceScene` is a subclass of `UIViewController` (not `SCNScene` right?). How is `self.view` configured (code or IBOutlet) ? Are you sure it's not `nil` ?

Comment: If ViewController with DiceScene is initial view controller its work, but if I call it from other ViewController its don't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in ViewController:

```
DiceScene* dice = [[DiceScene alloc] init];
[self setView:dice];
```